# Use of numba to speed up intersept calculation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numba

I am making a game which involves shadow casting.
To calculate the points on the lines I made this function.

```
def raySegmentIntersept(ray_start, ray_dir, segment_start, segment_end):
    segment_dir = segment_end - segment_start

    """
        find point where parametric equasions intersept
        A + t*r = B + u*s

        find the coeficient t for ray
        (A + t*r) x s = (B + t*s) x s

        find the coeficient u for segment
        (A + t*r) x r = (B + t*r) x r

        where x is cross function and cross is v1[0] * v2[1] - v1[1] * v2[0]
    """

    denominator = np.cross(ray_dir, segment_dir)

    if denominator == 0:
        return np.NaN

    t = (np.cross(segment_start - ray_start, segment_dir) / denominator)
    u = (np.cross(ray_start - segment_start, ray_dir) / -denominator)

    """
        since u is a segment it must be 0 <= u <= 1
        since t is a ray it must be 0 <= t
    """
    if 0 <= u <= 1 and 0 <= t:
        return ray_start + ray_dir * t

    return np.NaN
```

all four arguments (ray_start, ray_dir, segment_start, segment_end) are numpy arrays, (think of them as vectors, ie. shape=(2,).

I thought, that since this function is used quite a lot and it uses only maths in it, is it possible to speed it up?

The input looks (when printed) like this, where each line would be a different input

```
[ 120.  120.] [-0.70710678 -0.70710678] [160 240] [240 240]
[ 120.  120.] [-0.70710678 -0.70710678] [240 320] [160 320]
[ 120.  120.] [-0.70710678 -0.70710678] [320 240] [320 320]
[ 120.  120.] [-0.70710678 -0.70710678] [320 320] [240 320]
[ 120.  120.] [-0.70710678 -0.70710678] [160 320] [160 400]
[ 120.  120.] [-0.70710678 -0.70710678] [ 80 320] [ 80 400]
```

I would like to start to look at numba and maybe how to use the GPU for the computation. Is there a possibility to use any of the numba decorators? Do I need to refactor the code somehow?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The code consists of:

```
def raySegmentIntersept(ray_start, ray_dir, segment_start, segment_end):
    ...

class Vision:
    def see(self, obstacles):
         # prepare for calculation
         # call self.getInterceptsWithWalls(endpointAngles, visibleLines)

    def getInterceptsWithWalls(sellf endpointAngles, visibleLines):
         # for angle in enpointAngles do
         #     for tile in visibleLines
         #          for line in tile
         #              intercept = raySegmentIntersept(
         #                                  ray_start, 
         #                                  ray_dir, 
         #                                  segment_start, 
         #                                  segment_end)
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it? The [numba site](https://numba.pydata.org/) has a very illustrative example of a function decorator right on the front page.

Comment: That said, a general rule of thumb to where numba shines most: **loops**. Yours is a very short function. You will very likely not see any benefit from jit-compiling it, unless you call it from other compiled code. If you call it from Python the function call overhead will dwarf any optimizations.

Comment: I do call this function in a loop (as I now added to the edit) quite a lot, that is why I want to fasten it.

Comment: Then it would be best to include those loops as well, otherwise your code will be switching from and to Python all the time.